# How to find the number that best matches a given number

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, object

How to find the most suitable number for a given number.

For example. I have a number 8 and an array of objects.

```
let num = 8;
let data = [
  { fist:  {a: 1, b: 2}, second: {c: 11, d: 12}, number: 1 },
  { fist:  {a: 3, b: 4}, second: {c: 13, d: 14}, number: 7 },
  { fist:  {a: 5, b: 6}, second: {c: 15, d: 16}, number: 10 },
];
```

The closest number of all numbers in each object is 7.
How can I display the whole obit to which the number 7 belongs?

Comment: Is only `number` used in the comparison?

Comment: What happens if the distance is equal? EG `4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the obj with minimum distance from `num`:

```js
let num = 8;
let data = [
  { fist:  {a: 1, b: 2}, second: {c: 11, d: 12}, number: 1 },
  { fist:  {a: 3, b: 4}, second: {c: 13, d: 14}, number: 7 },
  { fist:  {a: 5, b: 6}, second: {c: 15, d: 16}, number: 10 },
];

const _isEmpty = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).length === 0;

const objWithClosestNumber = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(_isEmpty(acc)) { return item };
  const closestDist = Math.abs(num - acc.number),
    currentDist = Math.abs(num - item.number);
  acc = (currentDist < closestDist) ? item : acc;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(objWithClosestNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the array and find the smallest difference.

```js
let num = 8;
let data = [
  { fist: { a: 1, b: 2 }, second: { c: 11, d: 12 }, number: 1 },
  { fist: { a: 3, b: 4 }, second: { c: 13, d: 14 }, number: 7 },
  { fist: { a: 5, b: 6 }, second: { c: 15, d: 16 }, number: 10 },
];

let diff = Math.abs(num - data[0].number);
let ret = data[0];
data.forEach((x) => {
  if (diff > Math.abs(x.number - num)) {
    diff = Math.abs(x.number - num);
    ret = x;
  }
});
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array by choosing the item with the smaller absolute delta of given value and wanted value .

```js
let num = 8,
    data = [{ fist: { a: 1, b: 2 }, second: {c: 11, d: 12 }, number: 1 }, { fist: { a: 3, b: 4 }, second: { c: 13, d: 14 }, number: 7 }, { fist: { a: 5, b: 6 }, second: { c: 15, d: 16 }, number: 10 }],
    result = data.reduce((a, b) =>
        Math.abs(num - a.number) < Math.abs(num - b.number) ? a : b
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Return the whole obj, not only the closest number.